# Inheriting an interface given as generic argument

Tags: typescript

How would you achieve something like this in TypeScript?

```
interface Clonable<TAttributes> extends TAttributes { // ERROR: TAttributes is not an interface
    clone(): TAttributes
    copyFrom(input: TAttributes)
}

function(x : Clonable<{title:string,url:string}>) {
    alert(x.title) // ERROR: title is not an property of x
}
```

Background: I am trying to use TypeScript + Mithril + JSX. To have my attributes exposed in auto-completion, I need a property "attributes" with the types of my attributes; but I also want my class to have those attributes directly because it is way shorter to write "this.title" than "this.attributes.title".

Any option here?

Comment: It's not very clear what you're asking. Are you asking about how to implement it or how to "type it"? (or both..).  What is this nameless function? What is it supposed to do?

Comment: This code there is not valid. Here are the two errors it yields: 
- 'An interface may only extend a class or another interface.' at: '1,41'
- 'Property 'title' does not exist on type 'Clonable<{ title: string; url: string; }>'.' at: '7, 13'

I am looking for an alternative way to achieve this that would work.

Comment: Obviously, but what do you have so far? Is the `clone` and `cloneFrom` implemented? How would you use this? Please explain better what you have and what you want to do with it

Comment: Exactly as this code is trying to do. I want Clonable<X> be both a valid X (and therefore have "title" and "url" as properties) but also have the clone() and copyFrom() methods. The actual implementation is autogenerated JSX code so I cannot control that, I just want to typecheck it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an [intersection type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types):

```
interface Clonable<TAttributes> {
    clone(): TAttributes
    copyFrom(input: TAttributes)
}

type AttributesClonable<TAttributes> = Clonable<TAttributes> & TAttributes;

function doSomething(x : AttributesClonable<{title:string,url:string}>) {
    alert(x.title); // fine now
}
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20Clonable%3CTAttributes%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20clone()%3A%20TAttributes%0D%0A%20%20%20%20copyFrom(input%3A%20TAttributes)%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20AttributesClonable%3CTAttributes%3E%20%3D%20Clonable%3CTAttributes%3E%20%26%20TAttributes%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20doSomething(x%20%3A%20AttributesClonable%3C%7Btitle%3Astring%2Curl%3Astring%7D%3E)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20alert(x.title)%3B%20%2F%2F%20fine%20now%0D%0A%7D))